# How can I check the progress of my question being reviewed in the Reopen queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

I have a question, asked 22 hours ago, that is closed.

> Closed 21 hours ago.
> This post was edited and submitted for review 20 hours ago.

20 hours since my edit, I checkeed that the question is still in 'in review' status.

I checked the [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) and there are currently just over 400 questions in the queue.

I am a newcomer encountering this situation for the first time, is it normal to still be in review status after such a long time?

How can I see the progress of my question review, like how many reopen votes and how many close votes?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I see the progress of my question review, like how many reopen votes how many close votes?

You need to have [250 reputation](/help/privileges/view-close-votes) to view (and cast) reopen votes on your own question. If that banner is visible, the Reopen votes review queue item is still pending (if not, it would say something like 'The question was left closed in review), and it's hard to monitor its progress; you need [10k reputation](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to see past reviews, and even then, it's a very long list to scroll through (on Stack Overflow).

Currently, there are no Reopen votes for your question.

> is it normal to still be in review status after such a long time?

Sadly, yes. But even on sites with smaller review queues, reopening can easily take more than a day. When I have time, I'll try to write a SEDE query with some statistics (or someone else might do it ...)

Comment: 1. I checked the [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and `Close votes` had over 3,000 questions but finished voting in an hour, `Reopen votes` only had over 400 questions but took so long? 2. Is my question not yet reviewed, or does it keep getting skipped, or are there more `close votes` than `reopen votes`?

Comment: @FreedomFoolt Close votes often come from people just seeing the question rather than from the Close review queue. Not many people look at the queues, just 58 reopen queue reviews today (and 135 close reviews)

Comment: So I get it, there aren't many people who like to look at the `reopen queue`, relative to the huge number of users.